# Washing Machine leaking from bottom

Tags: repair, washing-machine

I have a Kenmore model 2130 top load washing machine.

When on the wash cycle, once it fills and then moves to agitate, it begins leaking.  It does not seem to leak while on the drain/spin cycle.  It does shake a lot when in agitate mode.

I opened the back to observe the leaking while in operation, and it seemed to be leaking water down from the middle of the washing machine, with water dripping down almost everywhere.  The water was not coming from the sides of the drum, seemingly from the middle.

I turned it on its side and checked the hose from the drain pump and also the inlet hoses and neither show any signs of leaking.

I recently replaced the actuator and also removed and reinstalled the water inlet valves.

What can I check to troubleshoot?

Comment: Chances are that the seals/bearings are leaking where the agitator shaft enters through into the washer tub. What's the complete model #?  By the time these parts fail, there's enough rusted parts that a new washer is usually needed.

Comment: @JACK 110.21302013.  It was working fine with no leaks until I replaced the actuator and removed and reattached the water inlet valve.  I think this machine is 7 years old (it came with the house when we bought it).

Comment: Consider replacing the washer although about 7 years not old.  I recently had a one foot X 3/4" diameter hose replaced . I showed the service guy where the problem was ( I have a physical problem and can no longer do all my own work). He charged $250 for the simplest repair possible ( in rural TX, not Manhattan). So at least get an estimate before the work.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Thanks for the comment and warning...I'll either be able to fix this or just buy a new one....not worth the repair fee.  I've now disassembled most of the machine and removed the tub seal.  I'm pretty sure the tub seal is the issue and will confirm once I get a new one and install it.  Doesn't appear to have much rust so I think this should work for a while with the new seal.